# How append multiple values in JavaScript global variable and convert them in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have javascript global variable `AdditionalTenentList` and I need to append muliple values in it at run time. I need to store value value in such a way that is search able by index and secondly I need to convert into JSON format so that I can post it to my script; say example I am taking 3 values from user at different timing and I want to append it to this variable on index 0,1 and 2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var AdditionalTenentList = {
    StudentUWLID: ""
};

function () {
    AdditionalTenentList.StudentUWLID = ? ? ? ? ?
}
</script>
```

Comment: what seems to be the problem/error?

Comment: I need to store multiple values in varaible on indexes

Comment: Use [collections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Indexed_collections_Arrays_and_typed_Arrays).

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Array and the `push` method:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/qz9vdmr5/)

```
var AdditionalTenentList = {
    StudentUWLID: []
};

var addElement = function (something) {
    AdditionalTenentList.StudentUWLID.push(something);
}

addElement('x');
addElement('y');
addElement('z');

console.log(AdditionalTenentList);
```

Comment: Do you need a JSON string? `var json = JSON.stringify(AdditionalTenentList);`

Answer (score 1):

You could work with a key value pair :

```
var obj = {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2
};
```

to set you do

`obj.key3 = "value3"`; 
or 
`obj["key3"] = "value3";`

to retrieve you do

`var result = obj.key3;` or `var result = obj["key3"];`

keep in mind that value1 can also be an array for instance, so you can do this then :

```
var obj = {
key1: []
}

obj.key1.push("a value");
```

to convert obj to json you do this : `var jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);`

And to convert back to javascript object you do this : `JSON.parse(jsonString);`